# CSS Object is empty even after providing styling

Tags: reactjs

I have used this component in other project so i am sure that it should work. However ,when combining different CSS the object is empty. Here is the code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import classes from './Dropdown.css';

class Dropdown extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            label:this.props.label,
            open : false,
            size : 'sm',
            dropStyle : 'outline',
            id : 'im-drop',
            name: '',
            options: []
        }
        this.status = 'close';
    }

    componentDidUpdate() {
        if(this.state.open === true) this.status = 'open';
        else this.status = 'close';

        if(this.props.name !== this.state.name) 
            this.setState({ name: this.props.name,});
        if(this.props.options !== this.state.options) 
            this.setState({options: this.props.options});
    }

    handleOpen = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        const isOpen = this.state.open;

        const newisOpen = !isOpen;
        if(newisOpen === true) {
            this.status = 'open';
            document.addEventListener('click', this.handleOutsideClick, false);
        }
        else {  
            this.status = 'close';
            document.removeEventListener('click', this.handleOutsideClick, false);
        }
        this.setState({open: newisOpen});
    }

    handleOutsideClick = (e) => {
        this.handleOpen(e);
    }

    handleSelect = (name, value, text, event) => {
        this.setState({
            label: text
        });
        let filter = {name: name, value: value};

        //this.props.action(filter, event);
        this.handleOpen(event);
    }

    render() {
        let dropDownClasses = [classes["im-dropdown"], 
                               classes[this.state.size],
                               classes[this.state.dropStyle], 
                               classes[this.status]];
        let itemcount = -1;
        let options;
        if(this.props.options !== undefined) {
            options = this.props.options.map(option => {
                itemcount++;
                return(<li 
                    key ={'opt_'+option.client+'_'+itemcount}
                    role="option" 
                    aria-selected="false" 
                    value={option.client} 
                    tabIndex={itemcount} 
                    onClick={this.handleSelect.bind(this, 
                        option.client, 
                        option.client, 
                        option.client)
                    }>  
                        {option.client} 
                    </li>)
            });
        }

        return (<div className={dropDownClasses.join(' ')}>
            <button 
                aria-haspopup="listbox" 
                aria-expanded="false" 
                className={classes["label"]} 
                onClick={this.handleOpen}>
                    <span>{this.state.label}</span>
                    <span className={classes["caret"]}>
                        <i className="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
                    </span>
            </button>
            <ul 
                className={classes["options"]} 
                role="listbox" 
                aria-labelledby={"im-drop_" +this.state.size+"_"+this.state.dropStyle}>
                {options} 
            </ul>
        </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Dropdown;
```

Comment: dropDownClasses  is an empty object and thats where the problem is.

Comment: You should remove all the code not pertinent to your styling question.